# Prove $A$ countable and $B$ a finite subset of A $\implies (A-B)$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone verify this. I am confused because I am not sure if I am being asked to strictly construct a bijection or not, although that is probably the case. The thing that confuses me is that I am not sure what "countable" means-- even on StackExchange people will say different things. Is countable a bijection from a set to the natural numbers? Is it an injection from the natural numbers to a set?

Am I supposed to talk about cardinality? Functions? What about the theorem that subsets of a countable set are countable?

---

Let us assume $A$ is countable and $B$ is a finite subset of $A$.

$A$ is countable which means it is either finite, or countably infinite.

If $A$ is finite, then $(A-B)$ is clearly finite (and countable) since the difference of two finite sets is finite.

If $B = \emptyset$, then $(A-B) = A$, which is countable so $(A-B)$ is countable.

Let us consider the case where $A$ is countably infinite.

Consider an arbitrary element $x \in (A-B).$

$\implies x \in A \land x \notin B$.

So $x\in A$.

It follows that $\forall x \in (A-B), x \in A \implies (A-B) \subseteq A$.

We can assume $(A-B) \neq A$ because $A$ is countably infinite and $(A-B)$ is finite, so $(A-B) \subset A$.

Suppose we define an injection $f$ as $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Since $(A-B) \subset A$ we can from that derive an injective function $g: (A-B) \rightarrow A$.

We can compose these two injective functions as $g \circ f: (A-B) \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Note that $|A-B|\le |A|,$ and hence $ \le \omega$, i.e., it is countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, I think you have the idea. Just note "$A$ is countable" does not mean $\# A = \# \mathbb{N}$, but that $A$ admits a bijection to a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so $\# A \leq \# \mathbb{N}$. Now to actually prove the claim, simply take your bijection and construct new one out of it by removing the elements of $B$.

Comment: I thought that $\#A \leq \#B$ for two sets $A$ and $B$ meant that there was an injection from $A \rightarrow B$? (which may or may not be a bijection).

Comment: I also thought that $\#A < \#B$ meant there was strictly an injection (not a bijection).

Comment: you are correct. But the two definitions are equivalent. An injection from $A$ to $B$ means one can construct to a bijection from $A$ to a subset of $B$ (this subset is just the image).

Comment: How about this?

$g$ as $g: (A-B) \rightarrow (\mathbb{N}-\{f(b):$ for some $b \in B\})$

Comment: exactly. just make sure you're rigorous about defining everything.

Comment: Honestly I don't really know what to do next. I can make $a \mapsto g(a)=f(a)$.

Do I actually need to show this is injective and surjective, but can I just say that since f is bijective, so is g? 

And even if g is bijective, it isn't technically to the natural numbers, it's to the natural numbers minus a finite number of elements...?

Comment: I'll start the proof, maybe you can finish it: there exists a set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ and a bijection $f: A \to S$. Define $g: (A-B) \to (S -\{f(b): b \in B\})$ by $g(a) = f(a)$. Now show $g$ is a bijection straight from the definitions.

Comment: remember, again, countable means admits a bijection to a subset of the natural numbers (not necessarily a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$) or alternatively an injection to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That throws me off a lot since my book tells me for a set S to be countable is that $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$ is a bijection, and I thought bijections went both ways (maybe this is wrong and it's why I'm confused.

Comment: this is not correct. a finite set is of course countable so that definition makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "countably infinite". I was told that countable meant finite OR countably infinite that is to say the definition I have given.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40138/discussion-between-j-s-r-and-gianttortoise1729).

Answer (score 1):

If $f:A \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective, $f:S\to \mathbb{N}$ is injective where $S \subset A$. Can you see why?

Comment: Well, $B$ being a finite subset of another set $A$ means there is an injection from $B$ to that set $A$, right?

Comment: Is there something like a set $A \approx \mathbb{N}$, 

$(A-B) = A - \{b \in B\}$, 

$(A-B) \approx (\mathbb{N} - \{n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, 

$\mathbb{N} \approx (\mathbb{N} - \{n \in \mathbb{N}\})$

$\implies (A-B) \approx \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Is this because there is an injection from $S$ to $A$, and you can compose the two functions to create an injection from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$? The thing that confuses me here is that there are conflicting definitions of "countable" I am getting. Some say it is a bijection to the natural numbers others tell me it is the other way around, or that it is an injection to the natural numbers...?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $A$ is countable, there is a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb N$.

Using this, show that there is a way to enumerate $A$ as $(a_n)_{n < \omega}$ such that $B = (a_n)_{n < m}$ for some finite $m$.

This then gives a fairly natural bijection of $A \setminus B$ to $\mathbb N$.